# Replace content in 'order' column with sequential numbers

Tags: postgresql

I have an 'order' column in a table in a postgres database that has a lot of missing numbers in the sequence.  I am having a problem figuring out how to replace the numbers currently in the column, with new ones that are incremental (see examples).

What I have:

```
 id  order  name
 ---------------
  1    50   Anna
  2    13   John
  3     2   Bruce
  4     5   David
```

What I want:

```
 id  order  name
 ---------------
  1     4   Anna
  2     3   John
  3     1   Bruce
  4     2   David
```

The row containing the lowest order number in the old version of the column should get the new order number '1', the next after that should get '2' etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) `row_number()` to calculate the new numbers. The result of that can be used in an update statement:

```
update the_table
   set "order" = t.rn
from (
  select id, row_number() over (order by "order") as rn
  from the_table
) t 
where t.id = the_table.id;
```

This assumes that `id` is the primary key of that table.

Comment: @simpleProgrammer: you can run that statement through JDBC